# How to use quoted variable in ggformula package

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggformula

I can use `aes_string` in ggplot, but how can I use this in `ggformula` package.

```r
pacman::p_load(ggformula)
plot_list = list()
names_y_axis = names(iris)[2:4]
plot_list = lapply(names_y_axis, \(x){
  gf_point(Sepal.Length ~ x, color = ~ Species)
})
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list)
#> Error in `FUN()`:
#> ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
#> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
#> Caused by error in `FUN()`:
#> ! object 'Species' not found
#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list)
#>   2. │ └─gridExtra::arrangeGrob(...)
#>   3. │   └─base::lapply(grobs[toconv], ggplot2::ggplotGrob)
#>   4. │     └─ggplot2 (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
#>   5. │       ├─ggplot2::ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x))
#>   6. │       │ └─ggplot2:::attach_plot_env(data$plot$plot_env)
#>   7. │       │   └─base::options(ggplot2_plot_env = env)
#>   8. │       ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
#>   9. │       └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
#>  10. │         └─ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
#>  11. │           ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
#>  12. │           │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
#>  13. │           │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>  14. │           │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>  15. │           │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>  16. │           │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  17. │           └─ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
#>  18. │             └─l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
#>  19. │               └─ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
#>  20. │                 └─ggplot2:::scales_add_defaults(...)
#>  21. │                   └─base::lapply(aesthetics[new_aesthetics], eval_tidy, data = data)
#>  22. │                     └─rlang (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
#>  23. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
#>  24.   └─rlang (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
#>  25.     └─handlers[[1L]](cnd)
#>  26.       └─cli::cli_abort(...)
#>  27.         └─rlang::abort(...)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You are missing `data=iris` in your call to `gf_point()`. That is what the error in your reprex is actually referring to ... the error has nothing to do with the formula part of your code. But you still should follow akrun's solution to get the desired plot.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using either `paste` or `reformulate` to create the formula

```
plot_list = lapply(names_y_axis, \(x){
  # gf_point(as.formula(paste("Sepal.Length ~", x)),
  gf_point(reformulate(x, response = "Sepal.Length"), 
  color = ~ Species, data = iris)
})
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Is the formula notation not required when using reformulate? And provide the code with ```paste``` too. Thanks.

Comment: @RamakrishnaS What is your expected output

Comment: I got it. But I would like to know is there any simple way to unquote the variable. like unquote(x) like that.

Comment: @RamakrishnaS or you could do `gf_point(as.formula(glue::glue("Sepal.Length~ {x}")), color = ~ Species, data = iris)`  Not sure what is simple for you